# base64 encoding of file in Python

Tags: python, encoding, base64

I want to use the function `base64.encode()` to directly encode the contents of a file in Python.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/base64.html#base64.encode) states:

> **base64.encode(input, output)**
>
> Encode the contents of the binary input file and write the resulting base64 encoded data to the output file. input and output must be file objects.

So I do this:

```
encode(open('existing_file.dat','r'), open('output.dat','w'))
```

and get the following error:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.encode(open('existing_file.dat','r'), open('output.dat','w'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 502, in encode
    line = binascii.b2a_base64(s)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

To my eye that looks like a bug in `/usr/lib/python3.6/base64.py` but a big part of me does not want to believe that...

Comment: try to open file in byte mode: `rb`/`wb`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

> when opening a binary file, you should append `'b'` to the mode value to open the file in binary mode

so changing

```
encode(open('existing_file.dat','r'), open('output.dat','w'))
```

to

```
encode(open('existing_file.dat','rb'), open('output.dat','wb'))
```

should work